# How can a static method change a variable? (Java)

Tags: java, class, variables

I have this class:

```
class Inventory {
    boolean smallknife = false;
    boolean SRLockerkey = false;
    void checkinv () {
        System.out.println("You have the following items in your inventory: ");
        System.out.println(smallknife);
        System.out.println(SRLockerkey);
    }
}
```

The Inventory test class

```
class InvTester {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Inventory TestInv = new Inventory();
        System.out.println("This program tests the Inventory");
        SKTrue.truth(TestInv.smallknife);
        TestInv.checkinv();
    }
}
```

and this class with a method to try to change the inventory

```
class SKTrue {
    static boolean truth(boolean smallknife) {
        return true;
    }
}


class SKTrue {
   static void truth(boolean smallknife) {
    smallknife = true;
  }
}
```

I would like to avoid using TestInv.smallknife = SKTrue.truth(TestInv.smallknife) and still change the variable but with a method. Is there a way that this can be done? I want that the truth method does the variable changing and I don't want to do the pass by reference part in the Inventory Test class. Thanks. Is there a way to do this in Java? (I also tried the second version which I think makes more sense)

Comment: Please observe proper syntax for code in a next post, it makes a lot of difference to people who need to read your question. That said, this looks convoluted. `if(thing)` is already part of the language, why are you writing a static truth evaluator that just adds indirection and makes the code hard to read? Even if you need to check sets, why not make that an instance method on the `Inventory` class?

Comment: Java is pass-by-value. Always. This means that method argument is always local copy of passed variable. This means that even if you assign new value to that local/copy variable, original variable will stay unchanged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to reference the variables directly (i.e. `TestInv.smallknife = blah`), the best practice in Java is to declare the variables as private and access them by getters/setters, e.g.:

```
class Inventory {

    private boolean smallknife;

    public boolean isSmallknife() {
        return smallknife;
    }

    public void setSmallknife(boolean smallknife) {
        this.smallknife = smallknife;
    }

}
```

Now, you can do this:

```
Inventory TestInv = new Inventory();
TestInv.setSmallknife(SKTrue.truth(blah));
```

It is called Encapsulation, you can read more about it [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm).